# Is there any way to bypass the Steam trading cool down?

Tags: steam

Do you always have to wait a certain amount of time when you want to trade on Steam if you change your password or change your Steam guard? Is there any way to surpass this or do I simply have to wait an entire month?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No there isn't a way. The whole reason for the delays is to protect your account in the event it was compromised.

More information can be found [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1047-EDFM-2932) (too much to list).

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to bypass the cooldown, as you said yourself, you must wait.

Answer (score 0):

Ladies and Gentlemen, i have found a way to kinda bypass the cooldown. The only requirement is at least 1 friend. All you need to do is have your friend buy the game as a gift, and give it to you, and then you can just pay them back later since there is no cooldown on recieving gifts, you should have no problem doing this.

Sorry for bad English i am Danish.